# Quartz Scheduler Could not Initialize DataSource: myDS

Tags: c#, quartz.net

I'm using Quartz 3.0.2 with MS SQL Server. I'm getting "Could not Initialize DataSource: myDS. There is no metadata information for provider 'SqlServer-20'\r\nParameter name: providerName." on GetScheduler.

This is my code:

```
StdSchedulerFactory schedFact = new StdSchedulerFactory();
IScheduler scheduler = await schedFact.GetScheduler();
```

This is my web.config

```
<configSections>
<section name="quartz" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler, System, Version=1.0.5000.0,Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
</configSections>
<quartz>
<add key="quartz.scheduler.instanceName" value="DefaultQuartzScheduler" />
<add key="quartz.threadPool.type" value="Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool, Quartz" />
<add key="quartz.threadPool.threadCount" value="1" />
<add key="quartz.threadPool.threadPriority" value="Normal" />
<add key="quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold" value="60000" />
<add key="quartz.jobStore.type" value="Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz" />
<add key="quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateType" value="Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.StdAdoDelegate, Quartz" />
<add key="quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix" value="QRTZ_" />
<add key="quartz.jobStore.dataSource" value="myDS" />
<add key="quartz.dataSource.myDS.connectionString" value="Data Source=.;integrated security=true;Initial Catalog=mudatabase;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Trusted_Connection=True" />
<add key="quartz.dataSource.myDS.provider" value="SqlServer-20" />
</quartz>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should change my provider to SqlServer

so my final config is

```
<configSections>
<section name="quartz" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler, System, Version=1.0.5000.0,Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
</configSections>
<quartz>
<add key="quartz.scheduler.instanceName" value="DefaultQuartzScheduler" />
<add key="quartz.threadPool.type" value="Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool, Quartz" />
<add key="quartz.threadPool.threadCount" value="1" />
<add key="quartz.threadPool.threadPriority" value="Normal" />
<add key="quartz.serializer.type" value="binary" />
<add key="quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold" value="60000" />
<add key="quartz.jobStore.type" value="Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz" />
<add key="quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateType" value="Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.StdAdoDelegate, Quartz" />
<add key="quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix" value="QRTZ_" />
<add key="quartz.jobStore.dataSource" value="myDS" />
<add key="quartz.dataSource.myDS.connectionString" value="Data Source=.;integrated security=true;Initial Catalog=mudatabase;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Trusted_Connection=True" />
<add key="quartz.dataSource.myDS.provider" value="SqlServer" />
</quartz>
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar issue while integrating Quartz 3.3.3 with .Net Core 3.1.

For .Net Core, you need to ensure "Microsoft.Data.SqlClient" nuget is installed for Quartz to work seamlessly with SqlServer data provider.